# Как абстрагировать понятие "Контейнера" в Java-технологиях

Tags: java, веб-программирование, spring, jboss, контейнеры

Изучаю программирование несколько месяцев, и уже знаком с `Java Core`, `коллекциями`, `принципами ооп`, а на данный момент пытаюсь понять, как именно устроены веб-приложения; разбираюсь с технологиями, которые мне пригодятся.

Суть вопроса: постоянно встречается понятие контейнера в книжках и учебниках. Например: `Spring` содержит контейнер; любой сервер - это по сути контейнер; при веб-разработке контейнером может служить `jboss`. Не могу понять, что имеется ввиду под словом контейнер. Если можно объяснить и поподробнее.

Comment: https://www.1000geeks.com/ru_RU/page/blog/spring-java-1/ - вот, прочитайте про спринг, там и про контейнеры есть. я когда-то писал эту статью для блога своей компании. думаю, поможет немного прояснить ситуацию...

Comment: Дмитрий, статья крайне полезна. Спасибо!

Comment: @ Artur Vartanyan не за что, рад, что вам это помогло разобраться

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Это специальным образом спроектированная программная среда, которая может быть расширена с помощью компонентов. Ну и как правило контейнер предоставляет очень много функциональности, которой вам бы самим пришлось писать с нуля. По факту вы изучаете программный интерфейс к этой среде и как правильно написать свой компонент, чтобы контейнер смог его подхватить и правильно использовать.

https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bnabo.html

---

Не знаю, поможет ли аналогия: вот есть игры и к некоторым играм разработчики позволяют писать людям свои собственные моды. Вот в данном случае в роли игры выступает контейнер, а в роли модов выступают ваши компоненты, которые органично встраиваются в систему и работают в ней.